# I want to insert the json file into documents object through lightning

Tags: json, document

My code is:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string savedocs(String con, string name){// parameters i am getting from Js healper class. Here con is the JSON string contains list of object data.
        document doc=new document();
        doc.Name=name;
        doc.ContentType='.json';
        doc.IsPublic=True;
        doc.Body=con;// here i am getting error. illigal assignment string to blob.
        doc.FolderId='00l6A000000IiYW';
            insert doc;
}
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert String into blob to assign the value. You can't directly assign string here.

```
Blob body = blob.valueOf(con);
doc.Body= body ;
```

Comment: i used that, But the record is not saved in to the document object.

Comment: @ArjunReddy Are you getting any exception? Did this method get called?